# How to create and where to put BeanShell scripts for Apache Maven Infoker plugin?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I need to create a zip file with my generated `.jar` and few other files needed by my project. Googling has led me to [Apache Maven Invoker plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/examples/post-build-script.html) (I use maven).

But it doesn't seem to use windows batch as I hoped (yeah, that would be too easy to create and debug). Instead, it enforces some cross platform ability by requiring BeanShell script. That's a scripting language that looks like java and works like java making me wonder how is it different from java.

My question is, using Netbeans, **how should I make a bean shell script** and **in which folder should I put it**. By "*how should I make*" I mean how shoild I make anything that executes and *indicates that it executed*.

Answer (score 1):

The location of the script is specified via the [postBuildHookScript parameter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html#postBuildHookScript)

> Relative path of a cleanup/verification hook script to run after executing the build. This script may be written with either **BeanShell or Groovy** (since 1.3).

I don't know how to create a zip file in BeanShell but you can also use Groovy and [creating a zip file in Groovy is easy](http://groovy-almanac.org/create-a-zipfile/):

```
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream  
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry  
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel  

String zipFileName = "file.zip"  
String inputDir = "logs"  

ZipOutputStream zipFile = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName))  
new File(inputDir).eachFile() { file -> zipFile.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(file.getName()))  
   def buffer = new byte[1024]  
   file.withInputStream { i ->  
      def l = i.read(buffer)  
      // check wether the file is empty  
      if (l > 0) {  
         zipFile.write(buffer, 0, l)  
      }  
   }  
   zipFile.closeEntry()  
}  
zipFile.close()
```